# fatal error encountered during command execution mysql data insertion

Tags: c#, mysql

I am getting the "fatal error encountered during command execution" error message when I am running this part of the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO clienti(nume, prenume, localitate, cnp, adresa, telefon, email) VALUES(@numen, @prenumep, @locl, @cnpc, @adresaa, @telefont, @emaile); ", conn);

        try
        {
            if (numen.Text.Length > 0 && prenumep.Text.Length > 0 && locl.Text.Length > 0 && adresaa.Text.Length > 0 && telefont.Text.Length > 0 && emaile.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numen", numen.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prenumep", prenumep.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locl", locl.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adresaa", adresaa.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefont", telefont.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emaile", emaile.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("Completati toate informatiile");
            MessageBox.Show("Clientul " + numen.Text + " a fost adaugat");
            numen.Text = "";
            prenumep.Text = "";
            locl.Text = "";
            adresaa.Text = "";
            telefont.Text = "";
            emaile.Text = "";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The info is extracted from some textboxes and it has to be written into the MySQL Database.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: that's mostly cause you are throwing an exception in `else` part

Answer (score 1):

You do not assign any value to `@cnpc` parameter, thus the execution of the prepared statement fails.

Comment: OMG now it is so obvious. Thank you!

Comment: In this case plsark the answer ad the accepted one to let other views know that the issue has been resolved.